# String being shortened suddenly

Tags: java, string, jgrasp

I read a string from the user. Then, when I use the string, I see it's being shortened. I don't know how or why? I need the whole `String`, not just a part of it!

This is the code:

```
String exp=null;
System.out.println("Enter an expression without nested parenthesis");
try {
    exp=read.next();
    System.out.println("exp 1 : " + exp); 
}
```

An example run:

```
input: 13 + 45
```

The example output is:

```
exp 1 : 13
```

Comment: You want `nextLine()`...

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the whole line:

```
String exp = null;
System.out.println("Enter an expression without nested parenthesis");
try {
    exp = read.nextLine();
    System.out.println("exp 1 : "+exp);
}
```

`read.next` reads only until the first whitespace.

Comment: that really worked, but why did this problem happen?!, i always use the read.next(); and it always works!?

Comment: @Duha because `next()` only returns the text up to the next space in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Using next() will only return what comes before a space

```
     String exp=null;
     System.out.println("Enter an expression without nested parenthesis");
     try {
        exp=read.nextLine(); //read line
        System.out.println("exp 1 : "+exp); 
     }
```